# Common boilerplate for multiple entry points in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In Webpack (4) are there ways to pass export(s) of a given entry file into a helper module, which itself acts as entry? Basically a way to "wrap" entry points.

Now, I know I can easily use CommonChunks to **import** into an entry, but what I trying to do is **export from** the entry for another module to actually do something in its place. Here's why.

I have a react application which I'm using Webpack to build. I am porting from a NEXT.js stack which, for my purposes, is a source of overhead. One feature I want to keep though, is putting routes in a `pages/` folder where I `export default Component` in each page, rendering automagically. This would be *very* nice behavior to have for a Webpack project.

Right now, I get my directory-based-multiple-entry roughly like this.

```
/* webpack.config.js */

const pages = {};

for(let route of fs.readdirSync('./pages')){
    pages[route] = path.resolve('./pages', route);
}

module.exports = {
    entry: pages,
    /* ... */
}
```

It works; but I do need to require and setup `ReactDOM.render` for every entry. Alone this is not a big deal, but when getting into HMR (hot-reloading) and other things, it adds a lot of redundancy. It also makes it harder to keep my code dev/production agnostic.

What I'd like to do is this. Have one module somewhere in my project which does the actual rendering of my pages, something like:

```
/* init.js */

const MyEntryPoint = require("‍♂️").default;

const intoContainer = 
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))

ReactDOM.render(MyEntryPoint, intoContainer);
```

with my multiple entry pages looking like

```
/* pages/login/index.js */

export default () => (
    <div>Welcome to the login page!</div>
)
```

I know there is a way to pass an array for given entries, but to my understanding they are concatenated and cannot import one another. My only other theory is to export each page as a library and manually include bootstrap code as a script-tag.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing. I found a [plugin](https://github.com/alibaba/entrypoint-wrapper-webpack-plugin) that looks like it would do what I want, except it doesn't seem to work with Webpack 4.

Comment: I did @cbnz, posted an answer to point you in the right direction. The need for this really was getting in my way too. However I've found that going the SPA route is much more viable nowadays (at least in react) given we have `<suspense>`, lazy loading, and better router tech like `@reach/router` and `navi` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did actually figure this out at some point. Ended up rolling my own solution called
[Webpack Intermediate Entry](https://github.com/gabeklein/webpack-intermediate-entry).

What it does is load a given `insert` file, specified in `IntermediateEntryPlugin`.

You can install and import this plugin via NPM as `webpack-intermediate-entry`.

It then replaces all entries with that file, and replacing `"__webpack_entry__"` import, with each in-turn.

Hopefully it helps!